# Image not loading - [Failed to load the given URL]

Tags: html, css

I'm getting this error when I inspect the element with FireFox: "Failed to load the given URL".

This is my HTML code:

```
<body id="page" class="page sidebar-b-right sidebars-1  isblog test">

    <div id="maininner" class="grid-box" style="min-height: 1320px;"></div>

</body>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.test #maininner{
    background-image: url(images/banderola_amarilla.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
```

The div "maininner" has information inside it, I just didn't add it as it would take up to much space. I have tried to change the URL of the css image in different ways "../images/" and moving it in different folders just in case but I still can't get the image to show.

What am I doing wrong?

You can check out the site here: [Check it out!](http://demo.open2logic.es/starlitefestival/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=203%3arosario-y-otra-noche-movida-nuevos-confirmados-en-starlite-2014&catid=76&Itemid=147&lang=es)

The image is suppose to be somewhere by "Noticias
ROSARIO Y OTRA NOCHE MOVIDA NUEVOS CONFIRMADOS EN STARLITE 2014".

Thanks.

Comment: Your relative path is off. Image that you want to inlcude is here: http://demo.open2logic.es/starlitefestival/images/banderola_amarilla.png but css is pointing to: http://demo.open2logic.es/starlitefestival/templates/yoo_tasty/css/images/banderola_amarilla.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct `url maybe: ../../../images/banderola_amarilla.png`

Comment: Wow.. I actually tried it this way: ../../images/banderola_amarilla.png and didnt think of adding a higher level, stupid of me. It works! Thanks :D

Comment: Template systems are confusing sometimes :)

Answer (score 3):

Give This

```
background-image: url("/starlitefestival/images/banderola_amarilla.png");
```

DONE...